# How to add breadcrumbs in product details page with category name in 2.3.4?

Tags: magento2.3.4

I want to add a category name in bread crumb in product detail page?. Can you help me how to do that?

Here is the example I want it.

> Home > Main Category Name > Sub category name > Product name

Currently, I can see like this:

> Home > Product name

But,  need to add a category into that.

Thanks you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> app/design/frontend/VendorTheme/ThemeName/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page>
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" remove="true" />
    <referenceContainer name="page.top">
        <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Breadcrumbs" name="product.view.breadcrumbs" template="Magento_Theme::html/breadcrumbs.phtml" />       
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

> app/design/frontend/VendorTheme/ThemeName/Magento_Theme/templates/html/breadcrumbs.phtml

```
<?php $crumbs = $block->getBreadcrumb(); ?>
<?php if ($crumbs && is_array($crumbs)) : ?>
    <div class="breadcrumbs">
        <ul class="items">
            <?php foreach ($crumbs as $crumbName => $crumbInfo) : ?>
                <li class="item <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $crumbName ?>">
                    <?php if ($crumbInfo['link']) : ?>
                        <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $crumbInfo['link'] ?>" title="<?= $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['title']) ?>"><?= $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['label']) ?></a>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <?= $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['label']) ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

> App/Code/Vendor/Module/Block/Breadcrumbs.php:

```
<?php

namespace Vender\Module\Block;

use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;

class Breadcrumbs extends \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Breadcrumbs
{

    /**
     * Catalog data
     *
     * @var Data
     */
    protected $_catalogData = null;
    protected $path = array();

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Data $catalogData
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(Context $context, Data $catalogData, array $data = [])
    {
        $this->_catalogData = $catalogData;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getTitleSeparator($store = null)
    {
        $separator = (string) $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('catalog/seo/title_separator', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $store);
        return ' ' . $separator . ' ';
    }

    public function getBreadcrumb()
    {
        $this->addCrumb(
                'home', [
            'label' => __('Home'),
            'title' => __('Go to Home Page'),
            'link' => $this->getBaseUrl()
                ]
        );
        foreach ((array) $this->path as $name => $breadcrumb) {
            $this->addCrumb($name, $breadcrumb);
        }
        return $this->getCrumbs();
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $this->path = $this->_catalogData->getBreadcrumbPath();
        $title = [];
        foreach ((array) $this->path as $name => $breadcrumb) {
            $title[] = $breadcrumb['label'];
        }
        return $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(join($this->getTitleSeparator(), array_reverse($title)));
        //return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    public function getCrumbs()
    {
        return $this->_crumbs;
    }

    public function getBaseUrl()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create module for this. I've created, try this:-

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0"></module>
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Product/FullBreadcrumbs.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © EAdesign by Eco Active S.R.L.,All rights reserved.
 * See LICENSE for license details.
 */
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Product;

use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeValue;

class FullBreadcrumbs extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    /**
     * Catalog data
     *
     * @var Data
     */
    private $catalogData = null;
    private $registry;
    private $categoryCollection;
    private $categoryFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Data $catalogData
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Data $catalogData,
        CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
        Registry $registry,
        CollectionFactory $categoryCollection,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->catalogData = $catalogData;
        $this->categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->categoryCollection = $categoryCollection;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getProduct()
    {
        return $this->registry->registry('current_product');
    }

    public function getCategory($categoryId)
    {
        $this->category = $this->categoryFactory->create();
        $this->category->load($categoryId);
        return $this->category;
    }

    public function getCategoryProductIds($product)
    {
        /** @var  $categoryIds  AttributeValue */
        $categoriesIds = [];
        $categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
        foreach($categoryIds as $categoryId){
            $categoryData = $this->getCategory($categoryId);
            $parentCategories = $categoryData->getparent_id();
            foreach($categoryData->getParentCategories() as $parent){
                array_push($categoriesIds, $parent->getId());
            }
        }
        return $categoriesIds;
    }

    public function getFilteredCollection($categoryIds)
    {
        $collection = $this->categoryCollection->create();
        $filtered_colection = $collection
            ->addFieldToSelect('*')
            ->addFieldToFilter(
                'entity_id',
                ['in' => $categoryIds]
            )
            ->setOrder('level', 'ASC')
            ->load();
        return $filtered_colection;
    }

    public function getCategories($filtered_colection)
    {
        $categories = '';
        foreach ($filtered_colection as $categoriesData) {
            $categories .= '<li class="item category'. $categoriesData->getId() .'">';
            $categories .= '<a href="' . $categoriesData->getUrl() . '" title="'. $categoriesData->getData('name') .'">';
            $categories .= $categoriesData->getData('name') . '</a>';
            $categories .= '</li>';
        }
        return $categories;
    }

    public function getProductBreadcrumbs()
    {
        $product = $this->getProduct();
        $categoryIds = $this->getCategoryProductIds($product);

        $filtered_colection = $this->getFilteredCollection($categoryIds);

        $categories = $this->getCategories($filtered_colection);

        $home_url = '<li class="item home"><a href="' . $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl() . '" title="'.__("Home").'">'.__("Home").'</a></li>';
        $product_name = '<li class="item product"><strong>' . $product->getName() . '</strong></li>';
        return $home_url . $categories . $product_name;
    }
}
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © EAdesign by Eco Active S.R.L.,All rights reserved.
 * See LICENSE for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::product/breadcrumbs.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/product/breadcrumbs.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
/**
 * @var $block Vendor\Module\Block\Product\FullBreadcrumbs
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php
$blockObj= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\Product\FullBreadcrumbs');
$fullbreadcrumbs = $blockObj->getProductBreadcrumbs();
?>
<div class="breadcrumbs">
    <ul class="items">
        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $fullbreadcrumbs ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks :)